# type 'ObjectId' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'value'

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart

I am trying to insert a document into my Mongo Database using the package [mongo_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/mongo_dart)

```
  var db = await Db.create(MONGO_CONN_STRING);
  await db.open();
  var coll = db.collection('reports');
  await coll.insertOne({
    "username": "Tom",
    "action": "test",
    "dateTime": "today",
  });
```

Runtime error on line 4

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'ObjectId' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'value'
```

Is it an issue with the package or is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Hey, have you solved this? I am also getting the same error. When I am passing the data like in map {} its working but I am passing map variable like `Map<String, dynamic> data` to `insertOne(data)`. it's giving error

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var db = await Db.create(MONGO_CONN_STRING);
  await db.open();
  var coll = db.collection('reports');
  await coll.insertOne({
    "username": "Tom",
    "action": "test",
    "dateTime": "today",
  }).toList();
```

Comment: insertOne is a function, why convert it to a list?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of the package?

I think your problem is related to this [issue](https://github.com/mongo-dart/mongo_dart/issues/68) in the GitHub Repo of the package but it is closed at Jul 25, 2015.

Comment: I am using the latest version of the package, yes. The issue is not the same as mine, the person facing that issue seems to be trying to manually parse the ObjectID whereas I am just going for a basic insert.

Answer (score 0):

The error is arising because you declared variables `db` and (collection name) outside the `static connect() async` function; declare them inside the function.

```
  var db = await Db.create(MONGO_CONN_STRING);
  await db.open();
  var coll = db.collection('reports');
  await coll.insertOne({
    "username": "Tom",
    "action": "test",
    "dateTime": "today",
  });


static connect() async {
var db = await Db.create(MONGO_CONN_STRING);
  await db.open();
  var coll = db.collection('reports');
  await coll.insertOne({
    "username": "Tom",
    "action": "test",
   "dateTime": "today",
  });
}
```

Comment: Please don't solicit compensation for posting an answer; if you are not fine with providing free advice, don't post answers. If you like, you are welcome to add a tip jar to your profile page, though. See also [How to not be a spammer.](/help/promotion)